# Parsing error when drawing SVG paths from GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gis, geojson, geomap

I made a world map with D3.js. Everything worked like a charm. I then used the same code for a different geojson file, depicting Sweden only, and got multiple parsing errors. Both json files have the same structure, are well-formatted and so on. The only difference is the coordinates, so I'm suspecting that's were the problem lies. Any ideas?

I'm using QGIS to convert shapefiles to the geojson format. The error I'm getting is: "Error: Problem parsing d='[the path string]'". And the path string contains NaN here and there.

**Sweden.json excerpt:**

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"id": 0,
"properties": {
    "KNKOD": "0114",
    "KNNAMN": "Upplands Väsby",
    "LANDAREAKM": 75.4
},
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                1620218.000425555,
                6599561.998826771
            ],...
```

**Countries.json excerpt**

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"id": 0,
"properties": {
    "type": "Country",
    "name": "Aruba"
},
"geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                -69.89912109375,
                12.452001953124991
            ],...
```

**Javascript**

```
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 1000)

d3.json("sweden/countries.geojson", function (data) {

var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
    .data(data.features)
    .enter()
    .append("g")

var path = d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator());

var areas = group.append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GeoJSON files aren't in the same coordinate system. The coordinates for Sweden look like they're in [UTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system). When converting to GeoJSON with QGIS, make sure that you're using the same coordinate system for Sweden as you did for the world file -- this should fix the error.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspected. So I guess D3 assumes the WGS 84 coordinate system?

Comment: The coordinate system depends on the [projection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections) you choose -- in your case Mercator.

Comment: For future reference, this tutorial did the trick for me: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/04/tutorial-working-with-projections-in.html